# C pass by reference without ampersand

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pass-by-reference, implicit-conversion

I was studying a socket tutorial in C, and I came across this:

```
char buffer[256];
bzero(buffer, 256);
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
```

However, as far I know, shouldn't the `buffer` variable be passed by reference (using &) to `bzero` and `read` functions? As well, the man pages for [bzero](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html) and [read](https://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/read.txt) specify that these arguments are pointers. Am I missing something?

Comment: The line `char buffer[256];` Allocates an array of size `256*sizeof(char)` on the stack and assigns the variable `buffer` a pointer to the start of the array. This means `buffer is of type `char*`, which is what those system calls want.

Comment: @Paul Please do not propagate the myth that arrays are pointers.

Comment: You can't pass an array in C, which decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure `bzero` is a deprecated POSIX function, you should use `memset(buffer, 0, 256)` instead.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Thanks! I did noticed something weird about it, was doing the same of memset. However, isn't my code, it is from a tutorial.

Comment: @IanAbbott I didn't? The pointer is to the beginning of the array.

Comment: @Paul The variable `buffer` holds the array itself, not a pointer to the start of the array. It "decays" to a pointer in most expressions (except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable buffer is declared as having an array type

```
char buffer[256];
```

Array designators used in expressions are implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to pointers to their first elements.

The function `bzero` changes elements of the array `buffer` So in fact all elements of the array are passed to the function by reference through the pointer to the first element of the array due to the mentioned above implicit conversion

```
bzero(buffer, 256);
```

As a result, the function can access and change any element of the array using the passed pointer and the pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

C has no pass by reference. You cannot pass things by reference in C. You can only pass by value.

The value passed here is a pointer to the first object in `buffer`. That is all either `bzero` or `read` need because an array always occupies a contiguous chunk of memory.

Answer (score 1):

When you call functions with an array,

```
char buffer[256];
bzero(buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

the array decays into a pointer:

```
void bzero(char *buffer, size_t len) {
    //...
}
```

If you on the other hand take the address of the array:

```
foo(&buffer);
```

A matching function would have to have a signature like:

```
void foo(char(*buffer)[256]) {
    // ...
}
```

The latter is pretty uncommon since it'd only accept arrays of a certain size.